# Trying to get multiple mysql instances running on Ubuntu dev box

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm trying to get multiple instances of mysql running on a dev box for some testing.  This guy is running ubuntu so the setup's a little different than our production setups.

I'd like to find the easiest way to basically sudo service start   and have it use a different .cnf init file (other than the distro default location of /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for making the necessary tweeks in Ubuntu in conjunction with the answer !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into the [mysqld_multi](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld-multi.html) tool ?

This will allow you to run different configurations and different distros using the same configuration file (/etc/mysql/my.cnf) and you could adjust the init.d script to use the mysqld_multi commands instead of mysqld.

Another tool might be [mysql sandbox](http://mysqlsandbox.net/), but I've never used that personally on any distro.

Comment: OK, nothing to add here, moving along. Oh yea, nice concise answer. +1 !!!

Comment: Actually Rolando, there is something to add :)  I did get it going with mysqld_multi quite nicely.  Apparently ubuntu runs app armor which protects various directories.


Running mysql_install_db to my new datadir was failing even running as root.

I had to update the apparmor config to allow the new paths appropriate access and then reload the apparmor config.

Comment: One after thought comment I thought would be worth pointing out for others stumbling across the solution to their problem is the implementation of their my.cnf w/ mysqld_mulit.

In short you'll have to add a [mysqld1] and [mysqld2] section to differentiate.  In my.cnt I just used an !include directive like

`[mysql1]

!include /etc/mysql/instanceA.cnf

[mysql2]

!include /etc/mysql/instanceB.cnf`

So I can edit instanceA.cnf or *B.cnf and not wonder which section i'm editing in a globbed together single my.cnf file.

(Sorry for the formatting, i still need to figure this out..)

Answer (score 2):

I am in the same situation daily. Instead of using mysqld_multi, what works OK for me is installing each MySQL copy to a separate tree, then running `mkdir -p data etc var/run var/log/mysql` and copying-fixing paths in a skeleton my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
basedir=/home/laurynas/usr/opt/mysql-5.5.12
log-error=/home/laurynas/usr/opt/mysql-5.5.12/var/log/mysql/error.log
socket=/home/laurynas/usr/opt/mysql-5.5.12/var/run/mysqld.sock
datadir=/home/laurynas/usr/opt/mysql-5.5.12/data

[mysqld_safe]
socket=/home/laurynas/usr/opt/mysql-5.5.12/var/run/mysqld.sock

[client]
socket=/home/laurynas/usr/opt/mysql-5.5.12/var/run/mysqld.sock
```

and finally running `scripts/mysql_install_db`. If several servers need to be running at once, then I throw in `skip-networking` or assign different TCP port too.